# azure function app python module import failure

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, python-import

I'm not able to execute my cloud function due to failures to import modules, module azure-identity for example, it's telling me module not found, I had my requirements.txt file:

```
msrestazure
azure-identity
azure.keyvault.secrets
azure-cli
```

and my code imports:

```
import logging
import json
import base64
import azure.functions as func
import requests
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
import os
```

> Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.identity'. Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 318, in _handle__function_load_request func_request.metadata.entry_point) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 42, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in call return func( * args, ** kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 85, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "/home/site/wwwroot/dworkerfn/**init**.py", line 6, in  from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential**

My files hierarchy:

```
├── dworkerfn
│   ├── function.json
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── launch-worker.sh
│   └── sample.dat
├── host.json
└── requirements.txt
```

This issue is not related to the module itself, I tried with different modules, requests for example and always the same issue.

Comment: Is this the error from your local environment? Or is it error output from the function running in the cloud?

Comment: Does this helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode#troubleshoot-modulenotfounderror

Comment: From the function running in the cloud.

Comment: @MarwenTaallah I have installed azure.identity using `pip install azure-identity` in local environment in my azure function app and then deployed it to azure function app which resolve the above mentioned error. Please check the images of 
[Before Deploying](https://i.imgur.com/Io159fs.png) and [After Deploying](https://i.imgur.com/0PW9Yii.png) logs.